# Iterating through Object Array to customise display of full custom taxonomy for custom post type

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy

I have read similar questions but I'm not getting a complete understanding of how to make this work.

I have created a custom post type and for it a custom taxonomy called **kernal_category**.

I am displaying my custom posts on the archive page and can output the lowest tier category using the code below:

```
if(get_the_terms($post->ID, 'kernal_category', true)) {
        $kernal_category = get_the_terms($post->ID, 'kernal_category', true);           

        foreach ($kernal_category as $category) {
              echo $category->name.' > ';
                # code...
        }
}
```

This is fine for posts that only have one term. But I have multiple posts which have tiered taxonomy. I want my code to display these taxonomies in full like a breadcrumb. So if there is only one term it should be as below:

**News**

If there are multiple it should be as below:

**News > Studio News > America**

To achieve this I want to add **>** symbols between all but the last term.  How can I do this since with the foreach loop I don't know how to instruct my code to not add the **'>'** symbol after the last term.

What I get currently is: **News > Studio News > America >**

I've tried to understand how to use **While** loop with objects but can't understand it. An example of my Array Object with multiple terms below:

```
 object(WP_Term)#3621 (10) {
   ["term_id"]=>
   int(7)
   ["name"]=>
   string(4) "News"
   ["slug"]=>
   string(4) "news"
   ["term_group"]=>
   int(0)
   ["term_taxonomy_id"]=>
   int(7)
   ["taxonomy"]=>
   string(15) "kernal_category"
   ["description"]=>
   string(0) ""
   ["parent"]=>
   int(0)
   ["count"]=>
   int(1)
   ["filter"]=>
   string(3) "raw"
 }
 [1]=>
 object(WP_Term)#3625 (10) {
   ["term_id"]=>
   int(9)
   ["name"]=>
   string(11) "Studio News"
   ["slug"]=>
   string(11) "studio-news"
   ["term_group"]=>
   int(0)
   ["term_taxonomy_id"]=>
   int(9)
   ["taxonomy"]=>
   string(15) "kernal_category"
   ["description"]=>
   string(0) ""
   ["parent"]=>
   int(7)
   ["count"]=>
   int(1)
   ["filter"]=>
   string(3) "raw"
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `echo`ing right away, save the category names into an array, and then you can `implode` the array, which means output it with whatever separators between items you wish:

```
<?php
if(get_the_terms($post->ID, 'kernal_category', true)) {
        // Create an empty array
        $categories = [];
        $kernal_category = get_the_terms($post->ID, 'kernal_category', true);
        // Save each category to the array
        foreach ($kernal_category as $category) {
              $categories[] = $category->name;
        }
        // Now output with implode
        echo implode(' > ', $categories);
}
?>
```

That way the spaces and caret separator will go between the items, but not after the last item.

Comment: Thanks for the reply - I see what you're getting out but I'm getting an `Warning:  implode(): Invalid arguments passed` error from the implode function. 

If I print_r the $categories array I get: `ArrayReference & Tools`

Comment: The problems seems to be that during the `foreach` loop the `$categories` array is somehow getting formatted as a string.  When I do `var_dump` it is a string being output, not the expected Array.

Comment: Edited above - it should be `$categories[] =` to add to the array instead of `$categories .=` which concatenates a string. Hadn't had enough caffeine. :)

Comment: Brilliant, that worked. Thanks!

Comment: A slight expansion on above. If my taxonomy has more than 2 levels it s not? ordering them Primary, Secondary, Tertiary... is there a simple way of ordering this